# Oracle listagg от nvarchar2(255), почему в результате null?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть таблица `table` с колонкой `name nvarcahr2(255)` в `Oracle 11`.

```
id |  name
---------
1  |  name1
2  |  name2
```

пишу запрос:

```
select listagg(name) within group(order by 1) from table
```

в результате вижу пустой результат(визуально), но он не `null`.

если сделать `listagg(to_char(name))` то в результате получаю нужную мне строку.
зачем явно `to_char`, если `listagg` и так приводит к `varcahr2`?

**UPD:**

```
select 
  listagg(name) within group(order by 1) is null as cols,
  case when listagg(name) within group(order by 1) is null then 1 
  else 0 end as isNull,
  length(listagg(name) within group(order by 1)) as length,
from table
```

такой запрос в результате вернет:

```
cols  |isNull  |  length
-------------------------
      |0       |  20
```

Запутался еще больше.

**UPD2** добавил воспроизводимый пример

```
create table tbl(
  id number,
  name NVARCHAR2(255)
);
insert into tbl(id, name) values (1, 'name1');
insert into tbl(id, name) values (2, 'name2');
commit;

select listagg(name) within group(order by 1) as col,
       listagg(to_char(name)) within group(order by 1) as col2,
       case when listagg(name) within group(order by 1) is null then 1 else 0 end as isNull,
       length(listagg(name) within group(order by 1)) as length, 
       ascii(substr((to_char(listagg((name), ' ,') within group(order by 1))), 1,1)) as codeSym
from tbl
```

Похоже, что в результате я получаю некоторое количество символов с кодом 0, которые не являются `null` с точки зрения `Oracle`, но в то же время символизируют `null` с точки зрения таблицы `ASCII`.
Возможно такое поведение вызвано какими то из `nls` настроек базы.

**UPD3** `select * from v$nls_parameters`

```
________________________________________________
NLS_LANGUAGE              |AMERICAN
NLS_TERRITORY             |AMERICA
NLS_CURRENCY              |$
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY          |AMERICA
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS    |.,
NLS_CALENDAR              |GREGORIAN
NLS_DATE_FORMAT           |DD-MON-RR
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE         |AMERICAN
NLS_CHARACTERSET          |CL8MSWIN1251
NLS_SORT                  |BINARY
NLS_TIME_FORMAT           |HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT      |DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT        |HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT   |DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY         |$
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET    |AL16UTF16
NLS_COMP                  |BINARY
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS      |BYTE
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP       |FALSE
```

Comment: можете привести пример с воспроизводимыми данными?

Comment: @MaxU добавил скрипт с примером

Comment: Можете показать какие у вас NLS настройки: `select * from v$nls_parameters;`? У меня ваш пример все показывает корректно

Comment: Попытка выполнить *воспроизводимый пример* на https://livesql.oracle.com показала вполне нормальный результат (выражения `col` и `col2` имеют значение `name1name2`). Точно так же, как и выполнение на sqlfiddle для 11g R2 http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a0daa/1 - правда, здесь `codesym` равен нулю.

Comment: @MaxU обновил вопрос

Comment: А меня проблема воспроизвелась, вопрос скорее всего в кодировке nvarchar. у меня NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET AL16UTF16. судя по всему listagg возвращает тип данных обычный varchar, а не nvarchar, при этом содержимое никак не изменяется. с помощью `dump()` разницу сразу видно (nvarchar выглядит как 0,116,0,101..., а простой varchar должен быть 116,101)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28812445/listagg-data-to-useable-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже что это баг (MOS Doc ID **19461687.8**):

> Bug 19461687  LISTAGG return value contains ASCII 0x00 bytes for
>   NVARCHAR with no delimiter specified

который, по утверждению Oracle, исправлен в след. версиях:

- 12.2.0.1 (Base Release)
- 11.2.0.4 Patch 16 on Windows Platforms